# inserting html code in jquery and give html syntax issue

Tags: jquery, html

I wanna use an html in jquery.I use this code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#registerNums").click(function(){
      var inputnums = parseInt($("#inputnums").val());
      for(var i=1; i < inputnums + 1; i++){
        var inputmems =
        '<div class="form-row">'+
           '<div class="form-group col-md-6">'+
            '<label for="inputmems">Enter the number of your input' + i + ' '  + 'membership functions:</label>'+
            '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputmems'+ i + ' ' + 'name="inputmems'+ i + ' ' + ' placeholder="Enter inputmems">'+
          '</div>'+
        '</div>';
        $("#1").after(inputmems);
      }
    });
  });
```

when i click on my registerNums button it append my form but i get the wrong syntax in my html code using inspect element:

```
<input class="form-control" id="inputmems1 name=" inputmems1="" placeholder="Enter inputmems" type="text">
```

that if you see after my id it extends name in it and other problems

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. there is some syntax issue while you create input string. It has to be like this

```
'<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputmems'+ i + '" name="inputmems'+ i +  '" placeholder="Enter inputmems">'+
```

Just change this line in your script

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/551312/)

Answer (score 0):

You should put the double quotes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#registerNums").click(function() {
    var inputnums = parseInt($("#inputnums").val());
    for (var i = 1; i < inputnums + 1; i++) {
      var inputmems =
        '<div class="form-row">' +
        '<div class="form-group col-md-6">' +
        '<label for="inputmems">Enter the number of your input' + i + ' ' + 'membership functions:</label>' +
        '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputmems"' + i + ' ' + 'name="inputmems"' + i + ' ' + ' placeholder="Enter inputmems">' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>';
      $("#1").after(inputmems);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#registerNums").click(function(){
      var inputnums = parseInt($("#inputnums").val());
      var inputmems = "";
      for(var i=1; i < inputnums + 1; i++){
        inputmems +=
        '<div class="form-row">'+
           '<div class="form-group col-md-6">'+
            '<label for="inputmems">Enter the number of your input' + i + ' '  + 'membership functions:</label>'+
            '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputmems'+ i + ' ' + 'name="inputmems'+ i + ' ' + ' placeholder="Enter inputmems">'+
          '</div>'+
        '</div>';
      }
      $("#1").append(inputmems);
    });
  });
```

please use var inputmems and append outside of for loop.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a problem with the html string that you're preparing. You can use **Template literals** which can make your life easier while preparing a html string with parameters.

```
var inputmems = `<div class="form-row"><div class="form-group col-md-6"><label for="inputmems">Enter the number of your input${i} membership functions:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputmems${i}" name="inputmems${i}" placeholder="Enter inputmems"></div></div>`;
```